# Why is my code giving me a segmentation/core dump error?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, matrix, transpose

The code is supposed to transpose a matrix:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

void transpose(int (&matrix)[3][3] ){
    int t[3][3];
    int rows = 3, columns = 3;
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int ii = 0; ii < columns; ii++){
            t[ii][i] = matrix[i][ii];
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int ii = 0; ii < columns; ii++){
            matrix[i][ii] = t[i][ii];
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int m[3][3] = { 
                  {1,2,3},
                  {4,5,6},
                  {7,8,9} 
                };
    int i = 0, ii = 0;
    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 3;
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i ++){
        for(ii = 0; ii < cols; i++){
            cout << m[i][ii] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    transpose(m);
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i ++){
        for(ii = 0; ii < cols; i++){
            cout << m[i][ii] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried returning an array, using a variable sized array, using different syntax, and even changing the array itself instead of using a second array. Even when it did work for a moment the transpose function did not work correctly. Now it gives a segmentation fault/core dump message.

Comment: Unrelated: *I've tried returning an array* Arrays are an elegant solution to a problem of the 1970s. You never wanted to pass an array by value because it took too long to copy and the duplication ate too much memory, so arrays decay to pointers and are always passed by reference (unless you wrapped the array in a structure). They're also returned by reference, which means a local variable array goes out of scope at the end of the function and the caller gets a pointer to invalid memory.

Comment: Unrelated: I think you can save yourself a lot of work by swapping values instead of rotating into `temp` and copying `temp` back.

Comment: @C12 This question is still on the list of unanswered questions. Didn't the answer I provided solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You index `m` out of bounds:

```
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i ++){
        for(ii = 0; ii < cols; i++) {   // note that you increase i, not ii, here
            cout << m[i][ii] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
```

You do the same mistake in both the inner loops in `main()`. The solution is to change the inner loops to this:

```
        for(ii = 0; ii < cols; ii++) {  // increase ii instead
            cout << m[i][ii] << " ";
        }
```

Comment: ... or use `j` to avoid the mental struggle of distinguishing `i` ("_eye_") from `ii` ("_eye-eye_")!

Comment: @PiCTo Naming the variables to something meaningful will help to avoid similar mistakes. I suggest `y` and `x` in this case.

Comment: Sure but, while not being words, `i`, `j`, `k`, ... are still meaningful based on their typical usage as loop variables, IMO.

I also believe that there is still a risk with `x` and `y` as there's no real convention for mapping (`x`, `y`) to rows/columns. You might have encountered the situation where `m[x][y]` (probably from the mathematical notation _(x, y)_ where _x_ is horizontal and _y_ vertical) was used while the matrix had been allocated as an array of rows (typically visualised/drawn as a vertical array of pointers to horizontal arrays) so that the proper access was `m[y][x]`.

Comment: For that reason, building on your comment, I believe that an even better naming convention when indexing a matrix is `row`/`col` (or `r`/`c`). Naming variables is an art, fundamental to writing clean code, isn't it?

Comment: @PiCTo If someone confuses `x` with `y` and vice-a-versa, I doubt naming them `row` and `col` would help. But, `row` and `col` are better names. Easier to search for at least.